# Is it possible to use a single Time Machine backup so that two Macs are always in sync?

Tags: mac, backup, time-machine

I have a Time Machine and two Macs.  ***I want both computers to be the same, not back them up separately***.

Is it possible to use one as a primary (always backing up from one) and then "downloading" the latest changes onto another?

Comment: Anybody knowing if a virtual NetBoot server can do this↑?

Answer (score 1):

Time Machine is not designed to do this. It will not make bootable backups, so you can't use a Mac as a destination for backup (and have this backup be "functional").

There are other solutions for synchronizing multiple machines. If iCloud/Dropbox/Google Drive type solutions are not sufficient for your needs, there are other tools that can sync - [Chronosync](https://www.econtechnologies.com/chronosync/synchronize.html) is one solution.

Comment: The thing is, I need/want more than just files to be synchronised.  I'm a software developer and I need/want my entire environment to be in sync (apps/plugins/extensions, system changes, etc)